# How to change table 'td' color based on key change in foreach loop

Tags: css, laravel, html-table

I am trying to set color when my `$key` value is changed. I mean I am generating a table when my `$key` is changing. Now I want to set a different bg-color when the **$key is changing** and a new table created. Now the `<th colspan="5">{{$key}}</th>` is changing and creating table for each `$key` I need to set  color that `$key` is changing.

```php
@foreach($lists as $key => $ser)
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_3">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5">{{$key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Destination</th>
            <th> Services</th>
            <th> Status</th>
            <th> Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($ser as  $s)
            <tr>
                <td style="background: rgb(176,224,230);"> TE 17 <br/>{{$s->sp}}</td>
                <td> {{$s->dd}}</td>
                <td> {{$s->ss}}</td>
                <td> {{$s->dt}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to store the value of `$key` in each loop. Then you can check to see if the `$key` is same as the previous one and change the color accordingly.

```
@php($prevvalue='')
@foreach($ser as  $s)
<tr>
    <td  style="background: {{$s->key == $prevvalue ? 'oldcolor','newcolor'}}"> TE 17 <br/>{{$s->sp}}</td>
    <td> {{$s->dd}}</td>
    <td> {{$s->ss}}</td>
    <td> {{$s->dt}}</td>
</tr>
@php($prevvalue = $s->key)
@endforeach
```

Comment: Showing `syntax error, unexpected ',' ` ` <tr>
                                                                        <td  style="background: <?php echo e($s->key == $prevvalue ? 'oldcolor','newcolor'); ?>"> TE 17 <br/><?php echo e($s->sp); ?></td>` @Xitish

Comment: Try `{{$s->key == $prevvalue ? 'oldcolor' : 'newcolor'}}` . Replace comma with colon.

Comment: I already tried this but showing `Undefined property: stdClass::$key`

Comment: On what basis do you determine the background color ? What is your `$key` that you are talking about?

Comment: in this foreach($lists as $key => $ser) loop every time $key is returing an ip value. Or another way we can set same color for `{{$s->sp}} ` will have same value and differen color for other. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kiqeA5hCMpuCkojZHWLi6MIfk4NQ04Xg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can u help to fix this? when looping each time the {{$s->sp}} printing a ip. So when the ip will same then it will the same color for them otherwise different.

Comment: If you are trying to change background color based on `$s->sp`, then change `$s->key` in the answer below to `$s->sp` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can first add class from blade to group elements having similar value :

```
@php($prev = null)
@php($counter = 1)
@foreach($ser as  $s)
    @php 
        $counter = $s->key == $prev || is_null($prev) ? $counter : $counter + 1;
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td class="td_color_{{ $counter }}"> TE 17 <br/>{{$s->sp}}</td>
        <td> {{$s->dd}}</td>
        <td> {{$s->ss}}</td>
        <td> {{$s->dt}}</td>
    </tr>
    @php($prev = $s->key)
@endforeach
```

This will give you following for the first column in each `<tr>` :

```
<td class="td_color_1">...</td>
<td class="td_color_1">...</td>
<td class="td_color_2">...</td>
<td class="td_color_2">...</td>
<td class="td_color_3">...</td>
<td class="td_color_4">...</td>
<td class="td_color_5">...</td>
```

Then in your css you have colors for these :

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.td_color_1 { background: red; }
    td.td_color_2 { background: blue; }
    td.td_color_3 { background: green; }
    td.td_color_4 { background: yellow; }
    td.td_color_5 { background: pink; }
</style>
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' ` end of the table @Mihir Bhende